# PiCameraから取得したstream(ByteIOデータ)を一時的に保存したい。

Tags: python3, raspberry-pi, camera, stream

※ByteIOについて理解しきれていない書き方をしているかもしれません。ご了承ください。
流れとして、

⓪　PiCameraで写真を撮り、変数 `stream` に保存
①　`stream` を別の変数 `stream_save` に保存
②　`stream` を `seek()` 関数や `truncate()` 関数で処理
③　`stream_save` はその後、別の処理
という流れで処理したいのですが、②をした瞬間 `stream_save` まで変更されてしまい、③でバグります。

```
    stream_saved = io.BytesIO()
    for foo in picamera.capture_continuous(stream, "png"):
        stream_saved = stream
        print(stream_saved.tell()) #801234などの数値
        stream.seek(0)
        print(stream_saved.tell()) #0
```

`stream_saved.tell()` の値を事前に保存することも考えたのですが、 `truncate()` などの関数も使うことを考えると対応しきれませんでした。
理解が浅く申し訳ないのですが、カメラから取得したbyteデータを2つの変数に保存、処理する方法を教えていただけますと幸いです。

追記
ByteIO()関数を使用したところコピーできました。ありがとうございます。
コピーした `stream_saved` を
https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/recipes1.html
の4.9を参考に以下のコードでsocketで送信しようとしたのですが、うまく動作しませんでした。。。
コピーした際に `.tell()`の値まではコピーされていなかったので `seek()` で元データの参照位置もコピーしたのですが
他にも `ByteIO(stream.read())` ではコピーされない要素があるのでしょうか？

```py
   stream_saved = io.BytesIO()
   for foo in picamera.capture_continuous(stream, "png"):
       stream_saved = io.BytesIO(stream.read())
　　　  stream_saved.seek(stream.tell)
       connection.write(struct.pack('<L', stream_saved.tell())) 
       connection.flush()
       stream_saved.seek(0)
       connection.write(stream_saved.read()) #ここが動かない
       # Reset the stream for the next capture
       stream_saved.seek(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

回答末尾のサンプルコードを参考にして、`io.BytesIO(stream.read())`でbyte[]データを複製してみてください。

ご質問のコードについて2行目でstream_savedを宣言していますが、4行目のfor文直後の`stream_saved = stream`で2行目のオブジェクトを破棄して`stream_saved`と`stream`が同一オブジェクトを参照してしまっています。
これによって`streamの`seek`や`truncate`でオフセットを変えたりクリアすると、`stream_saved`もオブジェクトが同じなので影響を受けます。

```
import io
stream = io.BytesIO(b'1234567890abcdef')

#バイト配列を複製して新しいBytesIOを作る
stream_saved = io.BytesIO(stream.read())
# stream.read() でオフセットが末尾に移動するので必要に応じて戻す
stream.seek(0)

# 以下は stream と stream_saved が独立しているか調査するコード
stream.seek(3)
print(stream_saved.tell()) # 0
stream.truncate()
print(stream_saved.read()) # b'1234567890abcdef'
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。別のものを作るというわけではなく、参照になるのですね。
少し理解が深まりました。

Comment: 追記内容について、もしご存知であれば情報をいただけますと幸いです。

Comment: すいません、print(stream_saved.read())するとオフセットが末尾に移動してしまうんですね。それに気づかずすごいアホなことしてました。解決しました。ありがとうございました。